# how to write firestore security rules with dynamic path?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My collection name is "omgcollection" and sample documents as below

```
{
  "omgcollection": {
    "documentId1": {
      "somekey": "somevalue"
    },
    "documentId2": {
      "somekey": "somevalue"
    }
  }
}
```

Here I used uid as the documentId, how to provide read only access to the documents based on $(request.auth.uid)

Below rule is not working

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/omgcollection/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
//customToken ~ uid = documentId1
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken( < customToken > ).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('auth error :', JSON.stringify(error));
});
var db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("omgcollection").doc("documentId1")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("data: ", doc.data());
    }, error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

This code return FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you actually want to limit access.  You're saying "based on $(request.auth.uid)", but that's not saying anything about what its value has to be or what it needs to match.

Comment: @DougStevenson: it's an `exists()` check.

Comment: OK, so what do you expect this rule to actually do, in english?

Comment: @Udhaya: can you show the code that you run that doesn't work?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, added the code. please check

Comment: Did you check whether `documentId1` is defined (correctly)?

Comment: Yes @Thomas van. Please post some working rules configuration